# Nasm: Macros not expanded as operands to instructions

Tags: assembly, macros, nasm

I wrote a small bit of assembly for nasm like this:

```
%macro register 1
    %if %1 = 0
        rax
    %elif %1 = 1
        rbx
    %elif %1 = 2
        rcx
    %endif
%endmacro

add register(1), register(2)
```

I expect that to evaluate to `add rbx, rcx`

However, `nasm -E test.asm` returns this, showing that the macro is not evaluated:

```
%line 10+1 test.asm

add register(1), register(2)
```

Compare that to this code:

```
%macro register 1
    %if %1 = 0
        rax
    %elif %1 = 1
        rbx
    %elif %1 = 2
        rcx
    %endif
%endmacro

register(1)
```

which is transformed into

```
%line 10+1 test.asm

rbx
```

Why the difference? How can I achieve what I expect in the first snippet?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use single-line macros for this, as they are expanded differently:

```
%define register_1 rax
%define register_2 rbx
%define register_3 rcx
%define register(x) register_ %+ x

add register(1), register(2)
```

```
$ nasm -E t4.asm
%line 1+1 t4.asm

%line 6+1 t4.asm

add rax, rbx
```

Comment: Is there documentation on how/why the two types of macro differ in expansion?

Comment: I mean what if my example must be applied to a more complicated macro?